Struggling to align images
I am trying to align 4 images with button links in a row. They are in a column now but if I try and align them in a row, the text goes in a different place than the images.
I have tried flex, align, etc.


<div class="polaroid">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt="Crime & Thriller" style="width:25%">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      <a href="Pages/Crime.html" target="_blank">Crime & Thriller</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="polaroid">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt="Female Empowerment" style="width:25%">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      <a href="Pages/Empowerment.html" target="_blank">Female Empowerment</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="polaroid">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt="Finance" style="width:25%">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      <a href="Pages/Finance.html" target="_blank">Finance</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="polaroid">
  <img src="images/translation.png" alt="Foreign Literature" style="width:25%">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      <a href="Pages/Translation.html" target="_blank">Foreign Literature</a>
  </div>
</div>




Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Please add in your CSS code

where are the </p> ending tags ?

@MisterJojo missing, but browsers should be automatically filling them in before the closing </div> tags so I don't think that's the issue.

"I am trying to align 4 images with button links in a row" - Looking at the width:25% styles used, it seems you're trying to do this manually.  Don't.  Use CSS flexbox.  "I have tried flex, align, etc." - What did you try and what didn't work as expected?  No such attempt appears to be made in the code shown.

Your primary mistake is that you aren't trying to align images. You're trying to align their containing elements. It's critical to realize that your actual structure isn't about images at all. See the various solutions linked above, paying particular attention to the flexbox solutions with flex-basis: 25%. Create your structure, then populate it with your content.

Also note the improvements I made to your question post for next time. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Protip: Close your paragraph elements. While it's not strictly required, it's best practice because it makes your markup more readable. The indentation looks odd to an experienced eye like it is now.

I don't think that's the issue for sure, but I don't think that's a good way of learning programming, with expecting system will always correcting your code. I also recommand you read how to ask a good question here, as well as other guidelines written especially for newcomers here, like this one
